# Shell Funtion string variables result blank?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have small script which have a function asking user input (name of user) and then I have echo function 
which is running the function and asking for input, 
After that I have echo the $User_name in last line (Users_name_is - )which is set in function but its result is black, I want to use $User_name in further script.
what i am doing wrong ?

```
 #!/bin/sh

funtion_one()
{
    read varname
        if [ $varname == skull ]; then
            echo "Nice to meet you $varname" 
            #User_name=$varname
        else
            echo "I dont know you $varname"
        fi

        User_name=$varname
}

echo Hello, who am I talking to?

while :
do
    case    $(funtion_one) in
        "Nice to meet you skull") break
        ;;
        "I dont know you") $(funtion_one)
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "Users_name_is - $User_name"
```

I want result  Users_name_is - skull

Comment: @anubhava not with While case loop

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$(funtion_one)`, you are executing the function inside a subshell, so any variables created cease to exist after the function finishes.

An alternative would be this:

```
function_one()
{
    read varname

    if [ "$varname" = skull ]; then
        echo "Nice to meet you $varname" >&2
    else
        echo "I dont know you $varname" >&2
    fi

    echo "$varname"
}

user_name=$(function_one)
```

Now `user_name` exists in the parent shell. The messages are sent to standard error, and the name that has been read is sent to standard output so that it can be captured by the command substitution `$()`.

Alternatively, you can simply execute the function in the parent shell:

```
# change 
echo $(funtion_one)
# to
funtion_one
```

But then all the variables used inside the function will continue to exist after it has been run.

---

It seems the function is getting in the way of you achieving what you want. I would restructure your code to something much simpler like this:

```
while read name; do
    if [ "$name" = skull ]; then
        echo "Nice to meet you $name"
        break
    fi

    echo "I don't know you $name"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
sorry but i have missed while loop in this. I have added now, can you help me with it ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to structure your code, and it seems like you're trying to do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

get_user_name() {
        local varname
        printf 'Hello, who am I talking to? '
        read varname
        if test "$varname" = skull; then
                echo "Nice to meet you $varname" 
                User_name=$varname
                return 0
        else
                echo "I dont know you $varname" >&2
                return 1
        fi
}

unset User_name
while ! get_user_name
do
        case "$User_name" in
        skull) break
        ;;
        esac
done

echo "Users_name_is - $User_name"
```

It's perfectly valid to use a function to get the input, but if you want that function to set a variable in the caller you cannot call it as a subshell, and it's easiest if the shell returns a value to indicate success or failure.

Comment: Check teh full script here with multi-pal functions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749678/shell-funtion-string-variables-result-blank-after-while-loop-and-case