# Shell Function string variables result blank after While loop and case?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

Why i not getting `echo "User password is= $typo"` result
How i can get result of typo in the end after while loop.

```
#!/bin/sh

pass_mes()
{
    read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
    echo $passvar           
}

password_verify()
{
    pass_ver=$(dscl /Search -authonly skull $typo 2>&1 | grep -i Authentication | awk '{print $1$5}')
        if [ "$pass_ver" == "Authenticationfailed." ]; then
            echo "Wrong_Password"
        else 
            echo "Correct_Password"
        fi
}

funtion_cancle()
{
        us_output=$(pass_mes)
            if [ "$us_output" == "User_Cancel" ]; then
                echo "User_Cancel"
            else
                echo "$us_output"
            fi
}


funtion_final_output()
{
    typo=$(funtion_cancle)
        if [ "$typo" == "User_Cancel" ]; then
            echo "User_Cancel"
        elif [ -z $typo ]; then
            echo "empty"
        else
            if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
                echo "WORKING_SKULL"
            else
                #echo "Wrong_Password"
                echo "NOT_WORKING_SKULL"
            fi  
        fi      
}

retry_funtion()
{
    echo "****Wrong Password Typed****"
}

cancel_funtion()
{
    echo "***User Cancled ***"
}


############## Script start ##################

echo "Script start"

while :
do
    case    $(funtion_final_output) in
        "NOT_WORKING_SKULL") retry_funtion
        ;;
        "empty") retry_funtion
        ;;
        "User_Cancel") cancel_funtion exit
        ;;
        "WORKING_SKULL") break
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "User password is= $typo"

echo "Continue script using password $typo"
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  `typo` is empty after the while loop because it was set only in subshells.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want typo result in end after while loop.  so that i can use that in rest of script

Comment: stop calling the functions in subshells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assinging typo like a local variable. In the main body of your script, the "typo variable was unset".

By other way, I don't understand the pourpose of the "funtion_cancle()" function. If the "us_output" variable is "User_Cancel" you return "User_Cancel", else if "us_output" is "a_valid_pass" you return the same...This function doesn't do anything

I recommend you make this:

1. Delete de "funtion_cancle()"
2. Assign "typo" at the beggining of the script.

An example:

```
#!/bin/sh


pass_mes()
{
    read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
    echo $passvar           
}

password_verify()
{
    pass_ver=$(dscl /Search -authonly skull $typo 2>&1 | grep -i Authentication | awk '{print $1$5}')
        if [ "$pass_ver" == "Authenticationfailed." ]; then
            echo "Wrong_Password"
        else
            echo "Correct_Password"
        fi
}



funtion_final_output()
{
        if [ "$typo" == "User_Cancel" ]; then
            echo "User_Cancel"
        elif [ -z $typo ]; then
            echo "empty"
        else
            if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
                echo "WORKING_SKULL"
            else
                #echo "Wrong_Password"
                echo "NOT_WORKING_SKULL"
            fi
        fi
}

retry_funtion()
{
    echo "****Wrong Password Typed****"
    typo="$(pass_mes)"
}

cancel_funtion()
{
    echo "***User Cancled ***"
}


############## Script start ##################

echo "Script start"
typo="$(pass_mes)"

while :
do
    case    $(funtion_final_output) in
        "NOT_WORKING_SKULL") retry_funtion
        ;;
        "empty") retry_funtion
        ;;
        "User_Cancel") cancel_funtion; exit
        ;;
        "WORKING_SKULL") break
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "User password is= $typo"

echo "Continue script using password $typo"
```

Comment: Nop its not working as you have set the one value of typo and if i type wrong password it go in loop and keep on telling wrong pass i have to quit terminal to stop it. I have used cancel function  because i am going to us gui message pop-up which have cancel options.

Comment: Yes, if typo is empty the script go into a infinite loop. To avoid this you can change the "retry_function" to get the password again. I edit the code with this fix.

Comment: Thank You A.Villegas its working fine, As I can see you have removed `funtion_cancle()` which i don't why i added as in main function User_Cancel already coming. But why you have added `typo="$(pass_mes)" ` in `retry_funtion()` ?  and if u can explain what else i was doing wrong that would be good for me :P

Comment: I add typo="$(pass_mes)" in retry_funtion() because if the users types an empty password, the script will come to a infinite loop. With this line, you give another chance to the user to introduce a correct password.

Comment: I see that You use the "funtion_final_output()" to check if the introduced password is ok, or there are any error with it. That is so usefull in my opinion but in this case I use a return value to indicate the type of the error. For example, if everything is ok I return 0, and if the password is not correct, I return a different error code for each type of error. For example: 

OK_CODE=0
ERR_CODE=1

    if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
        #return 0
        return $OK_CODE
    else
         #return 1
         return $ERR_CODE

But this is only my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

As people said before, parts of your script running in sub-shells, so `$typo` is lost.

Try this, it works:

```
#!/bin/sh

pass_mes()
{
    read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
    echo $passvar           
}

password_verify()
{
    pass_ver=$(dscl /Search -authonly skull $typo 2>&1 | grep -i Authentication | awk '{print $1$5}')
        if [ "$pass_ver" == "Authenticationfailed." ]; then
            echo "Wrong_Password"
        else 
            echo "Correct_Password"
        fi
}

funtion_cancle()
{
        us_output=$(pass_mes)
            if [ "$us_output" == "User_Cancel" ]; then
                echo "User_Cancel"
            else
                echo "$us_output"
            fi
}


funtion_final_output()
{
    typo=$(funtion_cancle)
        if [ "$typo" == "User_Cancel" ]; then
        ret="User_Cancel"
            echo "${ret}"
        elif [ -z $typo ]; then
        ret="empty"
            echo "${ret}"
        else
            if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
        ret="WORKING_SKULL"
                echo "${ret} ${typo}"
            else
                #echo "Wrong_Password"
        ret="NOT_WORKING_SULL"
                echo "${ret}"
            fi  
        fi      
}

retry_funtion()
{
    echo "****Wrong Password Typed****"
}

cancel_funtion()
{
    echo "***User Cancled ***"
}


############## Script start ##################

echo "Script start"

while read -r ret typo
do
    case    $ret in
        "NOT_WORKING_SKULL") retry_funtion
        ;;
        "empty") retry_funtion
        ;;
        "User_Cancel") cancel_funtion exit
        ;;
        "WORKING_SKULL") break
        ;;
    esac
done < <(echo $(funtion_final_output))

echo "User password is= $typo"

echo "Continue script using password $typo"
```

In my solution, run `while` loop passing `funtion_final_output` arguments to it like:

`while ... do ... done < <(echo $(funtion_final_output))`

To be able to pass values, you must not just `echo` them in functions, but assign it to variables (part of `funtion_final_output`:)

Was:

```
if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
                echo "WORKING_SKULL"if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
                echo "WORKING_SKULL"
```

Now:

```
if [ "$(password_verify)" == "Correct_Password" ]; then
        ret="WORKING_SKULL"
                echo "${ret} ${typo}"
```

I've made variables assignments like that in each `if` in `funtion_final_output`)

Next, when you pass variables in the final `loop`, you must read them.

`while :` rewritten to `while read -r ret typo`

Enjoy.